# Regarding installation error

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

After downloading Ubuntu 14.10 i tried to install it by shrinking the volume and Dual Booting it with Windows 8.

I got error message saying

`INVALID KERNEL IMAGE or INVALID BOOT OPTION`

Please help me out.

Comment: Are you using UEFI and if yes, is Secure Boot disabled?